# Injecting Service into DbContext doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, dbcontext

**I am getting An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll**

```
public SomeDbContext(IAuditLogService service)
            : base("name=SomeDb")
{

}

public static SomeDbContext Create()
{
   using (var container = new UnityContainer())
   {
      var service = container.Resolve<IAuditLogService>();
      return new SomeDbContext(service);
   }
}

container.RegisterType<DbContext, SomeDbContext>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ISomeDbContext, SomeDbContext>(new TransientLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IAuditLogService, AuditLogService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IAuditLogManager, AuditLogManager>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

The AuditLogService has the following constructor :

```
public AuditLogService(IAuditLogManager auditLogManager)
{
}
```

and AuditLogManager has:

```
public AuditLogManager(ISomeDbContext context) : base(context)
{
}
```

Basically I want to insert some logs when SaveChanges() is called. I wanted to passing in the AuditLogService with DI.

How can I set this up?

Comment: Does `AuditLogManager` have any dependencies?

Comment: yes to ISomeDbContext.

Comment: That's why the StackOverflow. Endless loop. ISomeDbContext needs IAuditLogService needs IAuditLogManager  needs ISomeDbContext , repeat. You have to break that circle.

Comment: Does unity have a way of breaking this circle?

Comment: Not out of the box. Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507503(v=pandp.30).aspx. Create a zero argument constructor for `SomeDbContext` that is used for the `AuditLogManager`. (assuming that class writes the auditlog to the db using  `SomeDbContext` )